# What is the difference between registerWebInterface and registerRestInterface and RestInterfaceClient?

Tags: rest, d, vibed

I can't understand by docs what is the difference between [registerRestInterface](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.rest/registerRestInterface), [registerWebInterface](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.web/registerWebInterface) and [RestInterfaceClient](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.rest/RestInterfaceClient).

Both of them can generate methods by class. But I can't understand when I should use one and when another.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understand the difference is to realize that `vibe.web.rest` and `vibe.web.web` are two different modules with a different use cases in mind:

### [vibe.web.rest](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.rest)

- meant for stateless communication
- requires to define an abstract interface
- [RestInterfaceClient](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.rest/RestInterfaceClient) can be used to communicate with other Rest interfaces
- A JS client can be generated from the API interfaces
- can be registered with [registerRestInterface](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.rest/registerRestInterface)

When to use:

- large public APIs
- API needs to be shared with others

-> [usage example](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/tree/master/examples/rest)

### [vibe.web.web](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.web)

- intended for web services
- allows direct access to the current session and request context
- provides many convenience functions based on the request (e.g. `redirect`)
- allows `@auth` ([example](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/tree/master/examples/web-auth))
- can be registered with [registerWebInterface](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.web/registerWebInterface)

When to use: web services, small APIs

-> [usage example](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/blob/master/examples/web/source/app.d)

I personally use `vibe.web.web` more often as for my small projects the overhead of keeping the interface files in sync isn't worth it.
Moreover, I like the convenient access to the request context and session variables in `vibe.web.web`. In fact, I maintain a [drop-in fork](https://github.com/teamhackback/hb-web) that adds more convenience feature (auto-serialization to/from Json, auto route /:param/ generation based on the method params, ...)